# Is is possible to combine two iterations in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop, iterator, hashmap

is it legal in Java to combine iterators like such?

```
for(int key : someMap.KeySet() && double value : someMap.values()) {
    //do something
}
```

This isn't something I could find anywhere else. I'm going to test it myself however if someone can save me the effort and knows this off hand it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Test it yourself and then come back with a question. You should show some effort before asking, that's how StackOverflow works. Read http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: You need to iterate over `someMap.entrySet()` to get what you're trying to achieve. Then you can access the key and value within a single iteration.

Comment: not exactly what you are looking for, but it is possible to loop through multiple list at once though. `List<String> list1=new ArrayList<String>();
  List<String> list2=new ArrayList<String>();
  for(int i=0,j=1;i<list1.size() || j<list2.size();i++,j++){
   //your stuffs
  }`

Answer (score 0):

No, foreach loops don't work that way in Java. Why do you have to loop through your `Map` values? You can just get the value to a given key directly:

```
for(Integer key : someMap.keySet()) {
    Double value = someMap.get(key);

    //do something
}
```

Or even better, iterate over the `Map`'s entry `Set`:

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer, Double> entry : someMap.entrySet()) {
    Integer key = entry.getKey();
    Double value = entry.getValue();

    //do something
}
```

Or, if you really really want to iterate over both, you can manually use iterators:

```
Iterator<Integer> keyIterator = someMap.keySet().iterator();
Iterator<Double> valueIterator = someMap.values().iterator();

while(keyIterator.hasNext() && valueIterator.hasNext()) {
    Integer key = keyIterator.getNext();
    Double value = valueIterator.getNext();

    \\ do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over `someMap.entrySet()` to achieve what you've sketched in your question. This way you can access the key and value of each entry (wrapped in a `Map.Entry<Integer, Double>` object) within a single iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly want to be iterating over the `entrySet()` of the `Map` like so

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer, Double> entry : map.entrySet()) {
   int key = entry.getKey();
   double value = entry.getValue();
   // do whatever with key, value
}
```

but for what it's worth, in Java 8 you can do

```
map.forEach((key, value) -> {
  // do whatever with key and value
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I'm fairly new to Maps and haven't learned all the features. you saved me a lot of time, thank-you!!